# How to match data in column - add non-contiguous row data for matching column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 5 | Cell 6 | Cell 7 | Cell 8 |

Goal is to do two things:

1. Match a specific item in Column A
2. Add only Column B and D (not C); return value

So I'm looking for : If A="data" then add row (cell) data from Column B and D.

I was using Sumif fine up until the point that I needed to add other data that is not contiguous. If it was I'd just be able to use B1:D2 to get all cell 2,3,4,6,7,8 data.

In this situation, I want to get a total of Cell 2 + Cell 4 only if Cell 1 matches what I'm looking for.

This should be recursive through the whole dataset. So if the row matches, add the column values, and then move on to the next one, if match, add column values, until there is a total value for the whole dataset.

Searched high and low but most examples use contiguous data.

Comment: Can you post few more examples with expected output, so it is easy to replicate.

Comment: Here's a link to a XLS with sample data: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yhmq4s8z0d24y908bawgf/sample-data.xlsx?rlkey=mzgef8ve9v6kfxl062vytegru&dl=0

Attempting to find totals (regular pay and separately overtime) for all departments.

As some of the data is not needed, like hours worked, I can't just add the whole row. I need to add just the columns with "money" figures in them.

Comment: Let me post this as an answer however i wasnt able to locate `Non-Exempt Overtime Earnings`

Comment: Have you tried to follow the solutions yet?

Comment: I've a somewhat basic understanding of Excel so I'm trying to unpack the answer(s).

Comment: It just seems like I'm missing something. All I'm looking to do is tell Excel that I need a total of multiple columns in a row if one item matches. So if yes, add the specified columns together in the row and then move on to the next one. If a match, add to the total. I guess it's easy, but then again I'm used to a database with a loop which would handle this quickly. Now that I think about it, I probably could make a database of the data, upload it and then run a query on it. Ultimately what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So are you saying the output is not matching as per your requirements? Is that so, if yes then please post using markdown data with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D11</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX($A$2:$BP$8,,XMATCH(A11,$1:$1))),"")
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E11</kbd>

```
=SUM(TOCOL((A11=$1:$1)*$A$2:$BP$8,3))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F11</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((A11=$1:$1)*$A$2:$BP$8,0))
```

---

Or, Single Dynamic Array Formula:

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G11</kbd>

```
=MAP(A11:A20,LAMBDA(α,SUM(TOCOL((α=$1:$1)*$A$2:$BP$8,3))))
```

---

Excel can be downloaded from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckA4K--KtcGeZT5G8?e=xY2N17)**